# UML class diagram Clarification I want to make sure if the rules needed are fulfilled

Tags: java, class, class-diagram

I am creating a car rental project where a customer can manage clients, cars, parking, reservations, contracts, bills and sanctions. this my UML class diagram :
I am not sure if this rule is fulfilled :

A customer can rent one or more cars that already exist in the parking lot.

I am not sure if it will be a simple association between the car and the customer or should I add the parking also to make it an association between 3 classes.

[image: this is my class diagram part 1]

[image: this is my class diagram part 2]

Thanks,

Comment: Go and ask your teacher. Examns are not useful if you let others anwer the questions.

Comment: I already answered the questions, it is me who made the class diagram I just wanna make sure if its correcte

Comment: Please be more specific. Maybe someone is bored here to go throug those 11 requirements. But this is no cross-check for my many problems page. Ask one specific question if you're in doubt for one of them.

Comment: concerning the seventh rule, A customer can rent one or more cars that already exist in the parking lot I am not sure if it will be a simple association between the car and the customer or should I add the parking too and make it an association between three classes. thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok. Please edit your question accordingly and I will tell you one more issue :-)

Comment: ok I will do it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the current design that might turn out to be tricky. If you would introduce a `CarStock` which holds all `Vehicle`s and their current status, this would be much easier. The current design requires `Client` to have associations to all `Vehicle`s in order to pick a single one. Remember how things work: you go up the rental company and ask for a car type and you get one. You don't go through the list of all cars owned by the company (thereby having insight who rented which car). Furher the relation between `Reservation` and `Vehicle` needs to be a 1--1.

The assocation `Client`-`Bill` is superfluous since the customer is already identified via the contract.

Comment: Actually your question is in no way about UML but purely about design. So I will remove the tag and send it to some other guys to take care.

Comment: Thank you, you have been so helpful to me